# How to find the index from a large scatter plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot with about 6000 items.

```
x = rand(1,6000);
y = rand(1,6000);
scatter(x,y)
```

Is there a way to find the index of a given point using the GUI?  (We zoom into data, and want to find the specific index that gave rise to a point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution:

Open a plot > data cursor > edit text update function

Set the text update function to:

```
function output_txt = myFunction(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');

% Import x and y
x = get(get(event_obj,'Target'),'XData');
y = get(get(event_obj,'Target'),'YData');

% Find index
index_x = find(x == pos(1));
index_y = find(y == pos(2));
index = intersect(index_x,index_y);

% Set output text
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)], ...
              ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)], ...
              ['Index: ', num2str(index)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end
```

Results:

[image]

Just FYI, if you want to do this programatically, then here's a good article on it [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips/).

Comment: What if it randomises more than one co-ordinate at that x value. Unlikely but it could happen.

Comment: @Ben I thought about this, you can use data from the y-coordinate too... I'll update it. The probability of this happening is "almost surely" zero.

Comment: Note:  If you use {x = get(get(event_obj,'Target'),'XData');} instead of the line above, you can make this work on any scatter plot, not just one that uses an x/y base namespace convention in the above.

Comment: @John Great note, I typically dont use evalin but in this case it was meant to be a very simple solution. Getting the XData property is definitely better though imo.

Comment: @jucestain totally get that.  That's one of the joys of stack overflow, we can improve the answers!  Although, my proposed edit for your answer, which included that code change got dropped....  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the X, Y position to search for the point:

```
%export the cursor to the workspace

possibleXpositions =  find(x == cursor_info.Position(1));
possibleYPositions = find(y == cursor_info.Position(2));
position = intersect(possibleXpositions, possibleYPositions);
```

position will hold the index of your selected random number.

As a one liner:

```
position = intersect(find(x == cursor_info.Position(1)), find(y == cursor_info.Position(2)));
```